# Convert xml to csv using dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a person.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <firstName>First Name</firstName>
    <lastName>Last Name</lastName>
</person
```

I have person.xsd,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="person">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I need to convert it to person.csv,

```
firstName,lastName
First Name,Last Name
```

I am using Anypoint Studio 7.3 on windows 10,
I am using a Listener, Read (file) xml.

See Transform Message dw below,

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",", header=true
--- 
payload
```

I am getting the following message on executing the flow,

```
"Cannot coerce Object { encoding: UTF-8, mediaType: text/xml; charset=UTF-8, mimeType: text/xml, raw: org.mule.weave.v2.el.SeekableCursorStream@2fdc554d } ({person: {firstName: "Shahjahan",lastName: "Ravjee"}} as Object {encoding: "U...) to Array, while writing CSV at payload." evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",", header=true
--- 
payload
    ".
```

Comment: @utechtzs Sorry, but I do not see where that `<people>` element comes from in the edit suggestion. And the GitHub link with the 20 MB zip-file (from OP's comment) has limited use too

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as the error message is stating, you're trying to convert an object into an array. This is a problem because in order to make a CSV, you need an array of arrays, or an array of objects.

You can see if you're currently outputting an object or array by setting your output to `application/dw`.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
---
payload
```

This will give you the following, which as you can see is an object:

```
{
  person: {
    firstName: "First Name",
    lastName: "Last Name"
  }
}
```

CSV needs an array, so we'll need to do a little transformation to get it to this:

```
[
  {
    firstName: "First Name",
    lastName: "Last Name"
  }
]
```

If you set the following script to `output application/dw`, you'll see that it outputs the above. At this point, you can be sure you have the correct format needed to create a CSV (array of objects, in this case), so switch it back to `output application/csv` and you should be good to go:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload pluck($)
```

Comment: Just to add, I left out `header=true` and `separator=","` because they are the default values for csv output and input

Comment: Hi jerney, Thanks for your super quick response. Unfortunately your fix did not work for me. Not sure why. I will upload my code to github shortly and link it through.

Comment: @jerney I had to adding a "%" before output and a " " after pluck. Maybe AnypointStudio7 is more forgiving?

Comment: Are you using DW 1.0, instead of 2.0?

Comment: I will update the question. If you change your answer to payload.people, it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following dw seems to have worked like a charm,

```
  %dw 2.0
    output application/csv headerLineNumber = 0 , header = true
    ---
    [{
        firstName: payload.person.firstName,
        lastName: payload.person.lastName
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Next, I would like to iterate over all the elements of the person.xml, currently the above dw (dataweave) is only doing it for the first row. Any ideas, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: @jerney's solution should work. Please edit your question with an actual xml example you'd like to use. What you'll be looking for is the .* operator.

payload.persons.*person pluck ($)

Comment: @utechtzs - look up the project on github https://github.com/ssravjee/mulesoft-4.x